# python way to find unique version of software

Tags: python, linux, sorting, split

I've multiple components of a software (let's call it XYZ) installed on my linux (RHEL 6.2) server running python 3.3.

```
~$ rpm -qa | grep -i xyz
XYZman-5.3.1.9-1.x86_64
XYZconnect-5.3.1.9-1.x86_64
XYZconsole-5.3.1.9-1.x86_64
XYZnode-5.3.1.9-1.x86_64
```

I'm trying to covert my install/upgrade script from shell to python. For that I need to fetch the version number, but only once. In my python script I've added the below code

```
>>> cmd = ("rpm -qa | grep -i xyz | awk -F[-] '{print $2}' | sort -u")
>>> sp = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
>>> (out, err) = sp.communicate()
>>> rcode = sp.returncode

>>> print (out.decode('utf-8').replace('\n', '')
>>> 5.3.1.9
```

I want to use python based commands instead of `awk` and `sort` in this. I think we can use `split()` for `awk`, but couldn't figure out the proper way for it.
Can we use python `sort` to get unique value like `sort -u` in shell.

Comment: it's not effective to grab the whole output from command line into python's variable. You better optimize your command-line pipeline: its feasible with `rpm -qa | awk <logic>`

Comment: Or even just `subprocess.check_output(['rpm', '-qa'])` and loop over the lines it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the delimeter to use in split() method, like this:

```
>>> cmd = ("rpm -qa | grep -i xyz")
>>> sp = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
>>> (out, err) = sp.communicate()
>>> v = []
>>> for line in out.splitlines():
...     if line.split("-")[1] not in v:
...         v.append(line.split("-")[1])
...
>>> print v
['5.3.1.9']
```

Answer (score 1):

It feels to me like you're trying to shoehorn python into a process where it doesn't really belong.  4 of the 5 lines you displayed were to get bash to talk to python.  I highly recommend you do the bash stuff on the bash side, and then just pass whatever you need as an argument into python.

Given all that, if you're still looking for "How do I get an iterable that only has unique elements?"  The answer is [sets](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set).  Key functions for sets are simply [add](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.add), [remove](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.remove) (or [discard](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.discard) if you're not sure the element is in the set), and [update](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.update) to merge one set into another.  Or, if you have a list of non-unique items and want them unique, construct a new set: `foo = set(my_non_unique_list)`

Be aware that sets are unordered.  Since you were talking about sorting, I don't think ordering is your concern, so sets should be just what you need.